# Minifying Vs. Readability confusion

Tags: javascript, html, css, minify

I'm looking at this [google guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml), which suggests for example:

> "Separate selectors and declarations by new lines."
>
> "Indent all block content, that is rules within rules as well as
> declarations, so to reflect hierarchy and improve understanding."

And so forth.

But at the same time, [Google suggests you minify your code here.](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources)

1. Isn't this contradicting?
   Or are Google's suggestions in the first guide are only meant for the creation phase of the code, rather than the phase when it's already online?
2. Also, If I minify a file, do I have to change its ending from `style.css` to `style.min.css`? I see many minified .js and .css files that come like this.
   Is it vital, or is that just to indicate to developers that if they want to modify the file, they better work on the non minified version first, and later minify it on their own?

Comment: "Or are Google's suggestions in the first guide are only meant for the creation phase of the code, rather than the phase when it's already online?" Yes.

Comment: Basically you will have two sets of files: One for development with indention and stuff and another set, which is minified for production use.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that is clearly answered by RTFM. The answer is actually in the question. Perhaps it's opinion based but that 'flag' did not seem entirely appropriate.

Comment: In other words, one for human to read & understand clearly and another for the machine to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or are Google's suggestions in the first guide are only meant for the creation phase of the code, rather than the phase when it's already online?

Yes. Minify when you publish the site.

> Also, If I minify a file, do I have to change its ending from style.css to style.min.css?

No. That is just a convention for when you distribute minified files with development files.

Answer (score 1):

Minification is only to save bandwidth when transferring the file over the network. It has no other purpose. A minified file is virtually impossible to work with for humans, so you're never going to minify the primary file you want to work on. You'll always create a minified copy of your actual file to send over the network, but you will not modify this copy by hand nor is anyone except a computer supposed to read it.

Comment: I see, so what do most people do when they want to use (or "steal") .css from another website, that was minified? if it's not readable, does it also serve a purpose of "protecting" the data, or is there a popular tool that decrypts the code back to readable state?

Comment: It does not protect from "stealing" in the least. First of all, it still works as is. Secondly, if the computer can read it, it can also format it nicely for a human to read.

Comment: @rockyraw There are simple ways to unminify css (see http://mrcoles.com/blog/css-unminify/ as an example)

Comment: Ok thanks. I wonder if there's an unminify tool that can break `font` to `font-size` and all other relevant font attributes?

Answer (score 1):

> 1- Isn't this contradicting? Or are Google's suggestions in the first
>   guide are only meant for the creation phase of the code, rather than
>   the phase when it's already online?

No, is not contradicting. Those suggestions are only meant for the development files. The production ready files usually are minified since that operation can save a lot of bandwidth across all files you may have, let say `.css` and `.js` but then readability will be lost (which is not needed in production anyways).

> 2- Also, If I minify a file, do I have to change its ending from
>   style.css to style.min.css? I see many minified .js and .css files
>   that come like this. Is it vital, or is that just to indicate to
>   developers that if they want to modify the file, they better work on
>   the non minified version first, and later minify it on their own?

No, you don't have to, for instance, you can have only one set of names for your development and production files, but it is a common convention (a good one) to have `.min.` files to easen the building and distributing of the files.